# Plus-sized amoeba escapes

Tags: combinatorics, board-games

As an extension to @WhatsUp 's question [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105238/amoebas-escaping-the-prison), the rules of which are included below, with the following differences:

> <strike>In one of the squares, there lives an amoeba (marked as a circle in the following pictures).</strike>

In some of the squares, there are amoebas (marked as green/yellow in the following picture).

> <strike>On the grid, there is a region called "the prison" (painted grey in
> the following pictures).</strike>

Here "the prison" consists of all yellow and green squares.

[image: plus-sign, 7 wide and 7 tall, bottommost square is yellow]

1. If the yellowish, bottommost square is unoccupied, can the amoebas make their escape?  How hard is it?
2. The night before their escape is launched, the yellow cell is filled with a new amoeba prisoner (all yellow and green are considered filled), what can they do now?

**Reference**

> There is an infinite grid of squares.
>
> In one of the squares, there lives an amoeba (marked as a circle in the following pictures).
>
> Amoebas cannot move, but they can perform their unique action: an
> amoeba can split itself into two amoebas, which are identical to the
> original one, and each will occupy a square that is (orthogonally)
> adjacent to the original square.
>
> Since every square can only accommodate one amoeba, a splitting can
> only happen when the amoeba has at least two empty adjacent squares
> (if there are more than two, then it can choose freely to which
> squares to split). Also, two amoebas should not split simultaneously,
> so that no conflict should occur.
>
> On the grid, there is a region called "the prison" (painted grey in
> the following pictures). The aim is to let the amoebas escape the
> prison, i.e. to reach a status that no amoeba is in the prison.

Comment: Something that might help people understand why the problem is difficult - if you're trying to get all the amoebas away from the center, their numbers grow at an exponential rate but the number of squares they can occupy only grow at a polynomial rate.

Answer (score 8):

Answer to Q2. As @Milo Brandt points out in a comment to the referenced Q there is the following half invariant:

> Put integer coordinates on the grid with (0,0) being the cross's center. Weight square (n,m) by $2^{-\lvert n \rvert - \lvert m \rvert}$. Then one can easily verify that

> [image]
>  1. the weight of the entire (infinite) board is 9 (c.f. picture)
>  
>  and
>  
>  2. the weight of squares occupied by amoeba never goes down.

> As the weight of the entire cross is $4\frac 1 2$ which equals the weight of its (infinite) complement the amoeba cannot escape in finitely many moves.

Comment: Rot13(Naq fvapr lbh pnaabg trg zber (guna 8/7) fdhnerf svyyrq ba z=0 be a=0 jvgubhg fhobcgvzny zbirf, vg vf abg cbffvoyr ng nyy)

Comment: There is also a very pleasing graphical proof/representation of the total weight being 9, part of which was my motivation for this question.

Comment: @Cireo like <see edit>?

Comment: @PaulPanzer if I could upvote twice ;)